await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules nodejs
Basically using Nodejs I connect to mysql and create a pool using below code which works fine,
db.js
const mysql = require("mysql")

exports.database = mysql.createPool({
    host: "host",
    port: 3360,
    user: "user",
    password: "password",      // hard-coded password
    connectionLimit: 10
});

    

products.query.js
const db= require("../db").database ;                    // importing connection pool

class ProductsQuery {

  static postProducts(id, cb) {

    await db.getConnection(...)                   // This works perfectly fine.

  }     
}

Things work fine and I'm able to execute all mysql queries.
The thing is, I don't want to use hard-coded password instead I want to use token, token gets generated using async await. To generate token I use below code,
Approach 1
db.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const mysql = require("mysql");

const createAuthToken = async () => {
    try {
        const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer();

        return await signer.getAuthToken({ // uses the IAM role access keys to create an authentication token
            credentials: {
                region: "region",
                accessKeyId: "accessKeyId",
                secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey"
            },
            region: "region",
            username: "username",
            hostname: "host",
            port: 3360
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

const token = await createAuthToken(); 

exports.database = mysql.createPool({
        host: "host",
        port: 3360,
        user: "user",
        password: token,
        connectionLimit: 10
});


Error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Apporach 2
(async function () {
        const token = await createAuthToken();  
        exports.database = mysql.createPool({
            host: "host",
            port: 3360,
            user: "user",
            password: token,
            connectionLimit: 10
        });
})()

but
const db= require("../db").database ;   // This is undefined

Apporach 3
exports.database= async () => {                   
    const token = await createAuthToken();  // able to generate token but exports return async function  
    return mysql.createPool({
        host: "host",
        port: 3360,
        user: "user",
        password: token,
        connectionLimit: 10
    });
}

tried other approaches as well but none of them is working and need help.
How can I make sure const db= require("../db").database is not undefined and it gets connection pool object using async await ?

if you want top-level await, have you considered using modules (i.e. you'll need to use  import/export instead of require/exports. after switching to using modules instead of commonjs

I actually can't change it due to some reasons.

There will definitely be a duplicate for this but my gut feel is you'll need to export a function that returns the promise

I'd say Apporach 3 is most likely to be useful - depending on how you require it, which you haven't shown

Approach #3 for sure... require('../db').database().then((db) => { ... })
